# Command to know the VirtualBox Guest Additions version installed at Ubuntu and Fedora

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, virtualbox

Having `VirtualBox` 6.1.38 and some Virtual Machines based on `Ubuntu` and `Fedora`, is possible install in peace `VirtualBox Guest Additions`, it for GUI and Server environments.

**Question**

- Through a command, is possible know the `VirtualBox Guest Additions` version?

If yes, what command is? It for Ubuntu and Fedora - I am assuming the command is the same for both

So far the unique way to confirm is checking the `/opt` directory where appears the `VBoxGuestAdditions-1.6.38` directory, but just being curious if there is a specific command available for those OS.

Comment: Try `VBoxClient --version`; this works regardless of how the client was installed (repo version or from GA ISO).

Comment: Your comment is correct - tested in both OS and works as expected - put your comment as an answer to mark it as valid as deserved. Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check the version of the installed **VirtualBox Guest Additions**, run this command:

For Linux-based systems:

```
VBoxClient --version
```

For Windows-based systems:

```
VBoxControl.exe --version
```

This works regardless of how the client was installed (system repo version or *Guest Additions ISO*)